# docker build" requires exactly 1 argument

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm

```
└─# docker build -f --help           
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

Build an image from a Dockerfile
How I can solve this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are you trying to archive? It's very unclear what you are trying to archive, as we don't know if your `Dockerfile` is in your current directory or inside another directory.

Comment: "requires exactly 1 argument" - anything unclear about that?

Answer (score 2):

The solution maybe:

```bash
docker build -f <docker-file> .
```

**You missed the `.`, aka the context path.**

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker build --help` and you'll get the help text for the build command, which includes help for the `-f` option.